# Animating a view with AutoLayout but it changes without actually animating

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a custom view subclass that I will provide all the code of for clarity. I have highlighted the relevant parts below.

Note: I know how to animate views using AutoLayout. The problem is not writing the animation code. The problem is that it updates the view but doesn't actually animate anything. It just jumps to the new size.

```
class ExpandingButtonView: UIView {
    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.textColor = .white
        l.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, for: .vertical)
        l.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, for: .vertical)
        return l
    }()

    let buttonStack: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.spacing = 8
        s.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        s.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        return s
    }()

    var collapsed: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            animatedCollapsedState()
        }
    }

    lazy var collapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
    }()

    lazy var expandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttonStack.bottomAnchor)
    }()

    init(title: String, color: UIColor, buttonTitles: [String]) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = color

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleCollapsed))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        titleLabel.text = title
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(buttonStack)

        buttonTitles.forEach {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
            button.setTitle($0, for: .normal)
            button.tintColor = .white
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            button.clipsToBounds = true
            button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
            button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, for: .vertical)

            buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collapsedConstraint,
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonStack.topAnchor),
            buttonStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            buttonStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func toggleCollapsed() {
        collapsed = !collapsed
    }

    func animatedCollapsedState() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.collapsedConstraint.isActive = self.collapsed
            self.expandedConstraint.isActive = !self.collapsed
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

It has two states...

1. Collapsed...

[image]

2. Expanded...

[image]

When you tap it the `tapGestureRecognizer` toggles the `collapsed` value which triggers the `didSet` which then animates the UI.

The animating function is...

```
func animatedCollapsedState() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.collapsedConstraint.isActive = self.collapsed
        self.expandedConstraint.isActive = !self.collapsed
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

However... it is not animating. It just jumps to the new size without actually animating.

I have removed another part of the view for the question. There is also a background image view that fades in/out during the UI change. That **DOES** animate. So I'm not quite sure what's going on here?

I have also tried moving the constraint updates out of the animation block and also tried running `layoutIfNeeded()` before updating them.

In all cases it does the same thing jumping to the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view's superview.

```
func animatedCollapsedState() {
    self.collapsedConstraint.isActive = self.collapsed
    self.expandedConstraint.isActive = !self.collapsed
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... ok, it's animating now (thanks) but jumping around everywhere. I'm really stumped on this one. The view seems to be jumping to the final position (without changing in size) and then animating its size.

Comment: OK... this is weird. I had to do `self.superview?.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` which is terrible :( will have to explore a new way of doing this I think. It works now though. Thanks :D

Comment: I just started making a video as a proof that it is working. :) glad i could help!